# Can't start Rails server! "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

When I try to run my rails app using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s -binding=128.199.95.219
```

I get this error

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:459:in `tcp_server_sockets'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `create_listeners'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:133:in `listen'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:114:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've googled many places but still find no definite answer which could solve this problem.

My app is running in Ubuntu (14.0.4) with Nginx and Unicorn at DigitalOcean

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **double dash** for the binding parameter, i.e.:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s --binding=128.199.95.219
```

See `rails s --help` for more info.

Comment: yea I found this out like three hours later. But yes this is the answer haha. Thank you.